# How to define a link in joomla Module Manager?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I am using Joomla to develop our website.

I have a link to show current openings page. In that current openings page, I place a link "Apply" and assign the link "http://rtbi.in/index.php/contact/jobs".
When i save and run that link redirects into "http://rtbi.in/"22http://rtbi.in/index.php/contact/jobs/"%22".

It Adds Some special characters automatically (the '%22'). help to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because of magic quotes. Turn off magic quotes in your php.ini and it should work.